# Examples for essential/superfluous submodules

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, definition, examples-counterexamples

Let $R$ be a ring. The [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Essential_extension) of essential/superfluous submodules of some $R$-module is pretty simple to understand, but I'm wondering about essential (no pun intended) examples for both notions.

What are the examples I should keep in my head when I hear about the essential/superfluous modules?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The classic example of an essential submodule is $\Bbb Z \subset \Bbb Q$ (considered as $\Bbb Z$-modules), or more generally a domain $R$ considered as a submodule of its field of fractions (again as $R$-modules).

The classic example of a superfluous submodule is the Jacobson radical $J(R)$ of a ring $R$ (considered as a submodule of $R$), or more generally $J(R)M \subset M$ for any finitely generated $R$-module $M$. See [Rotman](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=P2HV4f8gyCgC&pg=PA185&lpg=PA185&dq=example%20of%20superfluous%20module&source=bl&ots=v0Q6BMZBh7&sig=FqBOFnt-Ys3CepHqVtn_ylpKaS8&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiZ3vvOuKHdAhUHIcAKHTPzAtk4ChDoATABegQICRAB#v=onepage&q=example%20of%20superfluous%20module&f=false) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

These two things are pretty practical illustrations:

In any ring (with identity) the Jacobson radical is a superfluous submodule (on either side.)

For any commutative integral domain $D$ with field of fractions $F$, $D_D\subseteq_e F_D$.

---

*Doh, I was a little too slow with the above two, and Christopher has already covered them. I'll try to include some other things.*

Some other observations:

1. In an integral domain, all nonzero ideals are essential.
2. Consider any ring in which the right ideals are linearly ordered (such as a valuation domain.) . Then all nontrivial ideals are both essential *and* superfluous.
3. On the other hand: a nontrivial direct summand of $R_R$ is neither essential nor superfluous.
4. A ring has no proper essential right ideal iff it is a semisimple (Artinian) ring.  A ring has no proper superfluous right ideal iff it has trivial Jacobson radical. Notice that the first observation implies the second.